# Use regex in Javascript to get cents

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to formulate a regex expression in JavaScript to get the cents form a number that has a decimal point. For example, an expression that can get `27` from `454.2700000`. I know how to do this with split and substring but is there an easier way using just a regular expression. Thanks

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I think that regex is slower than substring and so on. At least in PHP regex is slower than string functions.

Comment: `'12.24'.split('.')[1]` seems perfectly adequate.

Comment: that doesn't account for the following zeros i had in my example

Comment: Why not just use `Math.round((x % 1) * 100)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really have a number and you want a number, why use strings?

```
var n=454.27;
var cents=Math.round(n*100)%100;
```

If n is a numeric string, multiplication converts it to a number:

```
var n= '454.270000';
var cents=Math.round(n*100)%100;
```

Answer (score 3):

The following parses out two digits after the decimal point:

```
/\.(\d{2})/
```

- `\.` means a dot
- `\d` means a digit
- `{2}` means two of them
- `()` to capture this part of the match

To get the match, use `.exec` and `[1]`:

```
/\.(\d{2})/.exec("454.2700000")[1]; // "27"
```

Answer (score 0):

The following regex will return you what you want:

```
/(?:\.)(\d\d)/.exec(454.2700000)[1]
```

Comment: The non-capturing group is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a regex test

```
/\.(\d+)$/.test(454.2700000)
```

and get your cents here, `parseInt(RegExp.$1, 10)`. Parsing the integer strips the zeroes.

Or if you always want two decimal places, replace my \d+ with pimvbd's \d{2} and then you can just to RegExp.$1 without the parseInt.

You can see it here http://jsfiddle.net/nickyt/qbsfY

Comment: It matches. I tested it in the JS console of Chrome unless he's pulling this number out of a string first.

Comment: Oops. Sorry, I misread your regex. But I still fail to see how `parseInt(2700000, 10)` will return `27`.

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker: I believe the number is parsed beforehand and when converted to a string, the zeroes have already disappeared.

Comment: @Tim - now that you mention it, the parseInt doesn't make sense, but for some reason it returns 27 not 270000.